# how to arrange div without disturbing the page design

Tags: html, css

how to position a div so that my page expands when some content is loaded. In the below image the div which I'm using is disturbing the page design.

[image: Div misplaced]

I'm using the following CSS:

```
#middlePanel {
    width:70%;
    float:left;
    background:#CCC;
}

#forum_act_container
{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}
#forum_act_header
{
    height:35px;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, #999); /* Standard syntax */
    text-align:center;
    line-height:33px;
}
#forum_act
{
     overflow:scroll;
     height:300px;
     padding:10px;
     border:#FFF 1px solid;
}
```

Below is their html structure:

```
<div id="middlePanel">
      <div id="forum_act_container">
        <div id="forum_act_header">Newest Forum Activites</div>
        <div id="forum_act"><?php echo $forum_activities; ?></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

What css code should I use so that the middlePanel div expands dynamically with the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#middlePanel` expands when You change `height` of `#forum_act` (or remove `height: 300px;` and fill div with elements). `#forum_act_container` You set `position:relative; top:20px; left:20px;` that why `#forum_act_container` is outside of `#middlePanel`. Instead of:

```
#forum_act_container
{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}
```

remove `left` and `top` position and add `padding` or `margin`, like:

```
#forum_act_container
    {
        width:300px;
        position:relative;
        padding:20px;
    }
```

Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/jc8mA/

or You can add extra padding-bottom for #middlePanel if want do not want to change postion: relative top, left.

Answer (score 1):

You need a clearer div in the middle panel so add

```
<div id="middlePanel">
      <div id="forum_act_container">
        <div id="forum_act_header">Newest Forum Activites</div>
        <div id="forum_act"><?php echo $forum_activities; ?></div>
      </div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```